No puedo encontrar un elemento en Selenium por su xpath
No puedo localizar el elemento button para hacer click sobre el, la grabacion no lo reconoce, el comando click sobre el xpath obtenido en diferentes navegadores arroja el siguiente error :
Failed:
13:06:11
Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //[@id="toolbar-switcher-container--2--dc__top_panel__viewFilter"]/div/div[2]/controls:app-button/button because of the following error: NamespaceError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//[@id="toolbar-switcher-container--2--dc__top_panel__viewFilter"]/div/div[2]/controls:app-button/button' contains unresolvable namespaces.
copio la estructura del elemento html :

    
        
           
           Aplicar
        
    

Tampoco con click at y las coordenadas X Y exactas.
Agradezco mucho vuestra colaboracion.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32232348/6009099

Gracias, no encontré la solucion en el link. Saludos.

Necesitas estudiar como funcionan los namespace en el xml porque en el link que te pase está la solución y también inglés
